# Using Apache to redirect specific route url

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, mod-proxy

I am using `Apache` to host and serve`Python` application service.
It is listening on port 80 for any URL. (`r^`)

I need to create a proxy router,
That the rule will be that any route that is (`r^/proxy/*.`) will redirect to `otherhostname:8080`

how can I force that rule with the existing running application?

How should I do that?

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: Could you share the rule you are thinking of putting in place, and possibly some of the surrounding config as context? Assuming you've found the config you think will work, you can in theory drop the into place and just reload apache to 'activate' the new config.